# Boost asio socket: how to get your own IP, port adress?

Tags: sockets, boost, ip, boost-asio

I have a TCP server using boost asio. I have accepted a socket connection. How to get IP, Port of my server machine as it is seen by my user server is currently communicating with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's [**`basic_stream_socket::local_endpoint()`**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/local_endpoint.html), but that's not necessarily what the other end sees if you are behind a [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) gateway.