# boost asio iostream - how to get local IP address

Tags: c++, boost, ip, boost-asio, local

Here is my problem:
I'm using boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream to connect to server:

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream s(IP, "1237");
```

And now I want to retrieve my own, local IP address. I have found somewhere in the depths of google how to do it with a [socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846050/boost-asio-socket-how-to-get-your-own-ip-port-adress), but what about a stream? 
I expect that since tcp::iostream is built on the top of a socket it should be something like:
s.local_endpoint().address()
but after a long search with google and duckduckgo I have found no clue how to do it. I have tried several most obvious permutations, but still no luck.
So, is there any simple way to do it, or do I have to use socket?
It only has to work on Linux, if it is important.

Comment: You seem to have the misconception that hosts have only one IP address.

Comment: The question is still valid: how can I retrieve *all* the IP addresses of the local host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Linux, Use [`getifaddrs(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) to get a list of interfaces for the local system.

Comment: I changed the application's behavior before you answered, so I forgot about this question, but yeah, that is the answer :)